# BlackBerry - Facebook extended permissions

Tags: rest, blackberry, facebook

I've just found a great sample of [Facebook Connect on Blackberry](http://www.baskoro.web.id/facebook-connect-blackberry-HOWTO.html) by Eki Y. Baskoro,

> The following is a short HOWTO on using Facebook Connect on Blackberry. I created a simple Facade encapsulating the Facebook REST API as well as added 'rough' MVC approach for screen navigation. I have tested on JDE 4.5 using 8320 simulator. This is still work in progress and all work is GPLed.

It works great for reading stuff.

**NB** Don't forget to [get Facebook App Key](http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php) and set it in TestBB class.

But now I want to post something on my wall. So I've add new method to FacebookFacade class using [Stream.publish API](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish):

```
 /***
 * Publishes message to the stream.
 * @param message - message that will appear on the facebook stream
 * @param targetId - The ID of the user, Page, group, or event where 
 *     you are publishing the content.
 */
public void streamPublish(String message, String targetId)
{
    Hashtable arguments = new Hashtable();
    arguments.put("method", "stream.publish");
    arguments.put("message", message);
    arguments.put("target_id", targetId);
    try {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(
        int new JSONTokener(sendRequest(arguments)));            
        int errorCode = result.getInt("error_code");
        if (errorCode != 0) System.out.println("Error Code: "+errorCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

 /***
 * Publishes message on current user wall.
 * @param message - message that will appear on the facebook stream
 */
public void postOnTheWall(String message)
{
    String targetId = String.valueOf(getLoggedInUserId()); 
    streamPublish(message, targetId);
}
```

This will return Error code 200, "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

First I thought it's related with *Facebook -> Application Settings -> Additional Permissions -> Publish recent activity (one line stories) to my wall* but even checked, no difference...

Then I've found this [post](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=33083) explains that issue related with [extended permissions](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions).

This in turn should be fixed by [modifying url a little in LoginScreen class](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=40420) :

```
public LoginScreen(FacebookFacade facebookFacade) {
    this.facebookFacade = facebookFacade;

    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
    data.append("api_key=" + facebookFacade.getApplicationKey());
    data.append("&connect_display=popup");
    data.append("&v=1.0");
    //revomed
    //data.append("&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html");
    //added     
    data.append("&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?" +
    "api_key="+facebookFacade.getApplicationKey()+"&display=popup&v=1.0"+
    "&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?"+
    "xxRESULTTOKENxx&fbconnect=true" +
    "&ext_perm=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access");     
data.append("&cancel_url=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failure.html");
    data.append("&fbconnect=true");
    data.append("&return_session=true");
    (new FetchThread("http://m.facebook.com/login.php?" 
            + data.toString())).start();
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working. Still Error Code 200 in return to stream.publish request...

Do you have any suggestions how to resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have posted the updated API on my website (http://www.baskoro.web.id/facebook-connect-blackberry-HOWTO.html) and this should solve this issue. Please let me know otherwise.

Salam. Cheers!

Eki

Comment: Hi, even I am using the same baskaro code but at first I was getting the invalid parameter error. After putting your code for LoginScreen constructor now I get Success but it is not redirected to another page. Can you please help me out in this? The page just displays success and nothing else.

Comment: Sunil, this issue has been resolved. Have a look at my website or go to the Facebook BlackBerry SDK project website directly (https://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk)

Comment: @Eki is this sdk work only with wi-fi connection? It not working properly on blackberry internet connection. please help..